# Unhandled Exception while using reflection in java

Tags: java, exception, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am currently making a minecraft mod, and I need to set my float to a private float of a base class. They hardcode a method and I am basically extending on it, but it uses the PRIVATE float "rendererUpdateCount"

I am trying to set my float "updateCount" to always equal the value of "rendererUpdateCount"

The problem is I can't seem to get the float's value with reflection.

Currently I am trying to do something like this:

```
Class er = EntityRenderer.class;
Field field = er.getDeclaredField("rendererUpdateCount");
```

The only problem is it throws `Unhandled exception type NoSuchFieldException` implying said float does not exist.

So how can I do this correctly?

Comment: P.S. I am leaning java as I go, with prior knowledge of javascript and javascript-like languages (gml)

Comment: That doesn't sound like it's actually throwing the exception; that sounds like the compiler is telling you you need a handler for that exception type. Do you know about checked exceptions?

Comment: Prior Javascript experience won't be particularly useful - the name connection between Java and Javascript was purely for marketing reasons, not because they're actually similar. They're very different languages.

Comment: I do not know about checked exceptions, could you explain briefly?

Comment: There are plenty of existing resources on the topic. For example, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/checked-vs-unchecked-exceptions-in-java/

Comment: Thank you everyone, I simply needed to surround in a try/catch

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we got `Unhandled exception...`, it means it's a `checked Exception` & demands try/catch ().

> **Checked**: are the exceptions that are checked at compile time. If some
>   code within a method throws a checked exception, then the method must
>   either handle the exception or it must specify the exception using
>   throws keyword.
>
> **Unchecked** are the exceptions that are not checked at compiled time.

In `Java exceptions` under `Error` and `RuntimeException` classes are `unchecked exceptions`, everything else under throwable is `checked`

Answer (score 0):

In java, you must handle checked exceptions, of which `NoSuchFieldException` is one. “Handling” is either catching it or declaring the method it’s thrown from to throw it. Let’s go with option 1, and you might as well catch the parent exception class `ReflectiveOperationException` because by the time you’re finished coding you’ll be potentially throwing a few more exception types from using reflection than `NoSuchFieldException`.

Try this:

```
try {
    Class er = EntityRenderer.class;
    Field field = er.getDeclaredField("rendererUpdateCount");
    field.setAccessible(true); // ignore/bypass it being “private”
    field.set(myInstance, myFloat);
} catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```